# How to replace values in List<interface>

Tags: java, android

I want to replace all commas in the display name in a List, how can i do it?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
                if(contacts.get(i).getDisplayName().contains(",")){
                    contacts.get(i).getDisplayName().replace("," , " " );
                    contacts.notify();
                }
            }
```

Comment: If my answer isn't useful due to not having enough context, I suggest you add some context. What is the type of `contacts`, and what does the interface look like?

Answer (score 5):

Well you need to *set* the display name, I suspect. Currently you're calling `String.replace` which creates a new string - but as strings as immutable, the existing display name won't be changed. I suspect you really want:

```
for (Contact contact : contacts) {
    String displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
    if (displayName.contains(",")) {
        contact.setDisplayName(displayName.replace(",", " ");
        contacts.notify();
    }
}
```

Or possibly better (single notification):

```
boolean anyChanged = false;
for (Contact contact : contacts) {
    String displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
    if (displayName.contains(",")) {
        contact.setDisplayName(displayName.replace(",", " ");
        anyChanged = true;
    }
}
if (anyChanged) {
    contacts.notify();
}
```

Note how unless you're using a list index for something *other* than getting the value out of the list, your code is cleaner if you use an enhanced for loop as above.

Comment: Thanks but i dont have setDisplayName method cuse it's a interface object

Comment: @Anna: Just because it's an interface doesn't mean we could guess that there's no setter... if there's nothing you can call to set the display name then, well, you can't change the display name.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much :)